# How to include a View the best way and call it?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm developing an Android App. On the Main Activity Screen there is a view, which calls the onDraw Method of the View class. But what is the right way to include the view?

1. include the view with  Tags in the xml. The View is drawn.
2. include the view with invalidate() and in the XML-File: onDraw is called two times
3. include the view with invalidate() and without tags in the XML-File: nothing is drawn
4. include the view with setContentView(): the view is drawn, but there is no ActionBar anymore

Can you give me a tip how to solve it?
Because we want something, the view is able to:
1. If we go to another Activity by click on the Action Bar Menu and the go back with the Up Button, the old view should be shown again and not draw again. How is that possible.

2. with an Intent to the MainActivity by click on a button from another Activity, the onDraw Method should be called.

I hope somebody can help me :)

The XML of the Main Activity:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The Content XML of the Main Activity:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">


   <view
       android:id="@+id/view"
       class="MyView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.437"
       app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The Main Actitivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //XML-Layout über die Ressourcen Variable holen
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Toolbar als ActionBar hinzufügen
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //Logo in Action Bar integrieren
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.hsd_logo_weiss);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there aren't reason to not do so...
Do as you say in point #1. It's the easiest method, once you wrote it in the xml and you verify that the view is regulary drawn, you could refer to it through the R object with

`findviewbyid(R.id.<viewID>)`

Just pay attention to the parent, make sure your view elements are where they are supposed to be, under the right parent

As for switching between intent, I don't know why it behave like you describe... some time ago i used actionbar like you do, but i didn't have those problems. Try to not use the onDraw() method if you can.

At least, you can remove it from problem's cause :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But is it possible not to use onDraw? Then the view isn't drawn. Or am I wrong? Is there a way to especially define when render the view and when take the old state?

Comment: With android:launchMode="singleTop" in the Manifest it works. The old state is taken. But only in Android 7 there is a problem: when i press the Up Button, all changes of the setting Activity  are assumed. But the changes should only be assumed when make a click on the apply button in the settings screen. On Andorid 5 and 6 it works fine.

Comment: If I recall correctly, in the activity.xml should be the setting to call the right (which was the word... ) "page" ,when you get on and when you leave, unless something in the code, **most likely a listener** , modifies something in it